# Boost Python wrap static member function overload with default argument

Tags: python, c++, boost, static, overloading

I have the attached C++ wrapper example for python: The member function (method) is static with default argument. So I use  BOOST_PYTHON_MEMBER_FUNCTION_OVERLOADS to define the overload function. There is no compilation error, however when I call the static member function I got the error as follows:

```
import boostPythonTest    
boostPythonTest.C.method("string")
```

> ```
> ---------------------------------------------------------------------------  ArgumentError Traceback (most recent call last)
> <ipython-input-4-ab141804179c> in <module>()
> ----> 1 boostPythonTest.C.method("string")
>
> ArgumentError: Python argument types in
> C.method(str) did not match C++ signature:
>
> method(class C {lvalue}, class std::basic_string<char,struct
> std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >)
>
> method(class C {lvalue}, class std::basic_string<char,struct
> std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >, int)
>
> method(class C {lvalue}, class std::basic_string<char,struct
> std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >, int, bool)
> ```

I don't understand why the first generated signature is "class C {lvalue}". If so the static member function needs an instance of C to be called, it looks contradict for me.

On the other hand, I define another static member function without using member function overload, it works for without the "class C {lvalue}" signature. For example:

```
boostPythonTest.C.noDefaultArgMethod("string", 0, True)
```

> Type:       function String Form: Docstring: noDefaultArgMethod( (str)arg1, (int)arg2,
>   (bool)arg3) -> int :
>
> ```
> C++ signature :
>     int noDefaultArgMethod(
> ```
>
> class std::basic_string,class
>   std::allocator >, int, bool)

Could anyone help explain the problem with BOOST_PYTHON_MEMBER_FUNCTION_OVERLOADS, or give some suggestion how to use it as real static member function with overloading?

```
#include <boost/python/module.hpp> 
#include <boost/python/def.hpp>
#include <boost/python/args.hpp>
#include <boost/python/tuple.hpp>
#include <boost/python/class.hpp>
#include <boost/python/overloads.hpp>
#include <boost/python/return_internal_reference.hpp>
#include <boost/python/register_ptr_to_python.hpp>
#include <boost/python/object/class.hpp>

using namespace boost::python;

class C {
public:
    static int method(const std::string &arg1, int arg2 = 0, bool arg3 = true) {
        return 1;
    };

    static int noDefaultArgMethod(const std::string &arg1, int arg2 = 0, bool arg3 = true) {
        return 10;
    };

};

BOOST_PYTHON_MEMBER_FUNCTION_OVERLOADS(method1, C::method, 1, 3)

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(boostPythonTest)
{

    class_<C>("C")
        .def("method", (int(C::*)(const std::string&, int, bool))0, method1())
        .staticmethod("method")
        .def("noDefaultArgMethod", &C::noDefaultArgMethod)
        .staticmethod("noDefaultArgMethod");

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe this line:

```
.def("method", (int(C::*)(const std::string&, int, bool))0, method1())
```

should look like this:

```
.def("method", &C::method, method1())
```

And you should use `BOOST_PYTHON_FUNCTION_OVERLOADS` instead of `BOOST_PYTHON_MEMBER_FUNCTION_OVERLOADS`, since there's no `C` object involved (static function pointers are just function pointers, they're not pointer-to-members).

There is also an example posted on [this wiki](https://wiki.python.org/moin/boost.python/FunctionOverloading) with overloading static functions, where the relevant section would be:

```
class X {
    static int returnsum(int m, int x = 10) { return m + x; }
};

BOOST_PYTHON_FUNCTION_OVERLOADS(X_returnsum_overloads, X::returnsum, 1, 2)

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(foo)
{
    class_<X>("X", ..)
        .def("returnsum", &X::returnsum,
            X_returnsum_overloads(args("x", "m"), "returnsum's docstring")
            )
        .staticmethod("returnsum")
        ;
}
```

That seems like exactly what you want.